# django two model serializer in filter count

Tags: python, django, serialization

i want django serializer list in filtering count
(Model <-> Foreign <-> Foreign(Count))

look my Model

```
class Test(models.Model):
   item = CharField
   title = CharField

class TestChild(models.Model):
   test = ForeignKey(Test)
   child_title = CharField

class TestChildType(model.Model):
   child = ForeignKey(TestChild)
   type = BooleanField
```

Test ChildType Model type field use

```
filter(type=false).count()
filter(type=true).count()
```

testFalseCount in filtering false value
testTrueCount in filtering true value

and want serializer

```
{
   item:'mouse',
   title:'goood Mouse'
   child:[
             {
                child_title:'childGood'
                testFalseCount:4
                testTrueCount:3
             },
             ...
         ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class TestChildSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    testFalseCount = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    testTrueCount = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    @staticmethod
    def get_testFalseCount(obj):
        return obj.filter(type=false).count()

    @staticmethod
    def get_testTrueCount(obj):
        return obj.filter(type=true).count()

    class Meta:
        model = Test

class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    child = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    @staticmethod
    def get_child(obj):
        return [TestChildSerializer(child).data for child in obj.testchild_set.all()]

    class Meta:
        model = Test
```